# How to cast 12/01/2019 12:00:00 a.m. to DATETIME in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to convert a String (12/01/2019 12:00:00 a.m.) to DATETIME.

I have tried with:

```
PARSE_DATE('%e/%m/%Y %k:%M:%S %P', Fecha_Desc)
```

no result ... any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.  First, you need `parse_datetime()`.  Second `a.m.` is not recognized.  So, remove the spaces:

```
SELECT PARSE_DATETIME('%e/%m/%Y %k:%M:%S %p', replace('12/01/2019 12:00:00 a.m.', '.', ''))
```

If you really want a date, convert to a date after converting to a `datetime` -- or just convert the first 10 characters.

Comment: Thank you very much :D.